# Kullback-Leibler divergence when the $Q$ distribution has zero values

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-approximation

For discrete probability distributions $P,Q$, the Kullback-Leibler divergence of $Q$ from $P$ is defined to be $$D_{\mathrm{KL}} ( P \mathop{\|} Q ) = \sum_i P(i) \ln \left( \frac{P(i)}{Q(i)} \right).$$

[Wikipedia's article on Kullback–Leibler divergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) states

> The Kullback–Leibler divergence is defined only if $Q(i)=0$ implies $P(i)=0$, for all $i$ (absolute continuity). Whenever $P(i)$ is zero the contribution of the $i$-th term is interpreted as zero because $\lim_{x \to 0} x \ln(x) = 0$.

What if $P(i)$ is very low number and in $Q(i) = 0$, because I just don't have enough samples? If I understand it correctly, the gain of $i$-th element should be $0$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sentence "The Kullback–Leibler divergence is defined only if $Q(i)=0$ implies $P(i)=0$ for all $i$" implies that $D_{KL}(P\|Q)$ is not defined if there is some $i$ such that $Q(i)=0$ but $P(i)\not=0.$

One could try to finagle a definition for $D_{KL}(P\|Q)$ in these cases using limits, as is done when $P(i)=0$ for some $P(i)$.  The relevant limit (using $p$ and $q$ in place of $P(i)$ and $Q(i)$) is
$$\lim_{q\to 0^+}p\ln \frac{p}{q}.$$
But as $q\to0^+$, $\frac{p}{q}\to\infty$, so the limit is infinite.

Some more intuitive explanations for why it's not defined (or why it's infinite) and what to do in those cases are given [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97938/calculate-the-kullback-leibler-divergence-in-practice).